# EF4 : How to include related objects when the relation is only defined on a subtype of a hierarchy

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, include, load

Here is my problem :
I have a code first EF4 model where I have a TBH hierarchy.
So, I have a Table In a database that is mapped over 2 classes (A1 and A2) that inherit from a base class A.
The class A1 defines a Navigation Property to another class (One-to-One for instance).
My problem is : How can I include the B related instances ?

I can't do something like this :

```
Dim res = From a In dbContext.A.Include("B_rel_obj")
          Select a
```

Because B_rel_obj is only defined for A1, and not in A nor A2.

My solution is :

```
Dim res = From a In dbContext.A
Dim res1 = From a1 In res
           Where TypeOf(a1) Is A1
           Select a1

For Each a1 As A1 In res1
  dbContext.Entry(a1).Reference(Function(a) a.B_rel_obj).Load()
Next
```

That works, but I don't like to loop over the results to Load().
Isn't there a way to load all the collection in one time ?

Comment: With TPH you are tempted to believe that B's can be loaded with the undiscriminated A's. After all, each A record has a BId (albeit `null` for A2). TPC or TPT make it much clearer that BId only belongs to A1 and that a union is the way go when you want to query both classes in one shot.